# Kafka Stream groupBy behavior: many intermediate outputs/updates for an aggregation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to play with Kafka Stream to aggregate some attribute of People.

I have a kafka stream test like this :

```
    new ConsumerRecordFactory[Array[Byte], Character]("input", new ByteArraySerializer(), new CharacterSerializer())
    var i = 0
    while (i != 5) {
      testDriver.pipeInput(
        factory.create("input",
          Character(123,12), 15*10000L))
      i+=1;
    }
    val output = testDriver.readOutput....
```

I'm trying to group the value by key like this :

```
    streamBuilder.stream[Array[Byte], Character](inputKafkaTopic)
      .filter((key, _) => key == null )
      .mapValues(character=> PersonInfos(character.id, character.id2, character.age) // case class
      .groupBy((_, value) => CharacterInfos(value.id, value.id2) // case class)
        .count().toStream.print(Printed.toSysOut[CharacterInfos, Long])
```

When i'm running the code, I got this :

```
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000012]: CharacterInfos(123,12), 1
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000012]: CharacterInfos(123,12), 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000012]: CharacterInfos(123,12), 3
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000012]: CharacterInfos(123,12), 4
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000012]: CharacterInfos(123,12), 5
```

Why i'm getting 5 rows instead of just one line with CharacterInfos and the count ?
Doesn't groupBy just change the key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `TopologyTestDriver` caching is effectively disabled and thus, every input record will *always* produce an output record. This is by design, because caching implies non-deterministic behavior what makes itsvery hard to write an actual unit test.

If you deploy the code in a real application, the behavior will be different and caching will reduce the output load -- which intermediate results you will get, is not defined (ie, non-deterministic); compare Michael Noll's answer.

For your unit test, it should actually not really matter, and you can either test for all output records (ie, all intermediate results), or put all output records into a key-value `Map` and only test for the last emitted record per key (if you don't care about the intermediate results) in the test.

Furthermore, you could use `suppress()` operator to get fine grained control over what output messages you get. `suppress()`—in contrast to caching—is fully deterministic and thus writing a unit test works well. However, note that `suppress()` is event-time driven, and thus, if you stop sending new records, time does not advance and `suppress()` does not emit data. For unit testing, this is important to consider, because you might need to send some additional "dummy" data to trigger the output you actually want to test for. For more details on `suppress()` check out this blog post: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-take-on-watermarks-and-triggers

Answer (score 0):

*Update: I didn't spot the line in the example code that refers to the TopologyTestDriver in Kafka Streams. My answer below is for the 'normal' KStreams application behavior, whereas the TopologyTestDriver behaves differently.  See the answer by Matthias J. Sax for the latter.*

This is expected behavior.  Somewhat simplified, Kafka Streams emits by default a new output record as soon as a new input record was received.

When you are aggregating (here: counting) the input data, then the aggregation result will be updated (and thus a new output record produced) as soon as new input was received for the aggregation.

```
input record 1 ---> new output record with count=1
input record 2 ---> new output record with count=2
...
input record 5 ---> new output record with count=5
```

What to do about it: You can reduce the number of 'intermediate' outputs through configuring the size of the so-called record caches as well as the setting of the `commit.interval.ms` parameter.  See [Memory Management](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#memory-management).  However, how much reduction you will be seeing depends not only on these settings but also on the characteristics of your input data, and because of that the extent of the reduction may also vary over time (think: could be 90% in the first hour of data, 76% in the second hour of data, etc.). That is, the reduction process is deterministic but from the resulting reduction amount is difficult to predict from the outside.

Note: When doing *windowed* aggregations (like windowed counts) you can also use the Suppress() API  so that the number of intermediate updates is not only reduced, but there will only ever be a single output per window.  However, in your use case/code you the aggregation is not windowed, so cannot use the Suppress API.

To help you understand why the setup is this way:  You must keep in mind that a streaming system generally operates on unbounded streams of data, which means the system doesn't know 'when it has received all the input data'.  So even the term 'intermediate outputs' is actually misleading:  at the time the second input record was received, for example, the system believes that the result of the (non-windowed) aggregation is '2' -- its the correct result to the best of its knowledge at this point in time. It cannot predict whether (or when) another input record might arrive.

For *windowed* aggregations (where Suppress is supported) this is a bit easier, because the window size defines a boundary for the input data of a given window.  Here, the Suppress() API allows you to make a trade-off decision between better latency but with multiple outputs per window (default behavior, Suppress disabled) and longer latency but you'll get only a single output per window (Suppress enabled).  In the latter case, if you have 1h windows, you will not see *any* output for a given window until 1h later, so to speak.  For some use cases this is acceptable, for others it is not.

Comment: Ok but how can I test that ? Why when I rerun my test with exactly the same code the count are incremented by 5 ?

Comment: How can you test what?

Comment: This answer is not really to the point, because TopologyTestDriver effectively disables caching...

Comment: Oops, didn't spot the `testDriver.pipeInput()` line in the code. :-)