# TopologyTestDriver with streaming groupByKey.windowedBy.reduce not working like kafka server

Tags: unit-testing, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have a streaming app that in part is meant to do a group by key during a windowed period of 1min then reduce records to 1 key/value.  It then logs and processes to produce a new set of output records.

When I run this against an actual kafka cluster (using confluent platform) with multiple inputs with same key in same minute I get 1 record logged and 1 set of output records produced.

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> changes()
{
    return kstream -> kstream
        .groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(durationSeconds)))
        .reduce((value1, value2) -> value1)
        .toStream()
        .peek( (key, value) -> logger.info("Reduced Trigger: {} = {}", key.key(), value) )
        .flatMap( (ignoredWindowedKey, value) -> service.getChanges(value) );
}
```

When trying to complete tests for this process using the TopologyTestDriver it is logging each input record producing a set of output for each input, which does not match the actual runtime.

Here is the test:

```
    public static final String INPUT_TOPIC = "changes-in-0";
public static final String OUTPUT_TOPIC = "changes-out-0";

private static final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();

private TopologyTestDriver testDriver;
private TestInputTopic<String, String> inputTopic;
private TestOutputTopic<String, String> outputTopic;

private final Instant recordBaseTime = Instant.parse("2020-01-03T10:00:00Z");
private final Duration advance10Sec = Duration.ofSeconds(10L);

private static Properties streamsConfiguration;

@Mock
private DirtyProductService service;

@InjectMocks
private ProductPublisherApplication app;

@BeforeAll
public static void intialize()
{
    // Need to be set even these do not matter with TopologyTestDriver
    streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "TopologyTestDriver");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "dummy:1234");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, (10 * 1024 * 1024L));
}

/**
 * Setup Stream topology
 * Add KStream based on @StreamListener annotation
 * Add to(topic) based @SendTo annotation
 */
@BeforeEach
public void setup()
{
    //Create Actual Stream Processing pipeline
    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, String> input = builder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC, Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));

    //Add the stream processor.
    app.setDurationSeconds(30L);
    final KStream<String, String> output = app.changes().apply(input);

    output.to(OUTPUT_TOPIC, Produced.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));

    testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration, recordBaseTime);
    inputTopic = testDriver.createInputTopic(INPUT_TOPIC, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer(), 
        recordBaseTime, advance10Sec);
    outputTopic = testDriver.createOutputTopic(OUTPUT_TOPIC, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());
}   

@AfterEach
public void tearDown() 
{
    try 
    {
        testDriver.close();
    } 
    catch (final RuntimeException e) 
    {   // https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6647 causes exception when executed in Windows, ignoring it. Logged stacktrace cannot be avoided
        System.out.println("Ignoring exception, test failing in Windows due this exception:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}   

@Test
public void multipleNotifyWithinWindowShouldTriggerOnce() throws InterruptedException 
{
    final KeyValue<String, String> expected = new KeyValue<>("1234", "sku");
    when(service.getChanges("Poll 1")).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(expected));

    inputTopic.pipeKeyValueList(Arrays.asList(new KeyValue<>("1", "Poll 1"), new KeyValue<>("1", "Poll 2"), new KeyValue<>("1", "Poll 3")));

    testDriver.advanceWallClockTime(Duration.ofSeconds(30L));       

    //read the value and validate it.
    assertEquals(outputTopic.readKeyValue(), expected);
    //should be no more records in the output topic
    assertTrue(outputTopic.isEmpty(), outputTopic.getQueueSize() + " remaining records");       
}
```

**question** Can anyone assist in figuring out how to get the tests to act like the runtime?

Comment: This project has more elaborate test cases which you might want to analyze: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-inventory-count/README.adoc
Can you try to see if they match with what you are trying accomplish?

Comment: no, unfortunately those examples are what I was working off of and couldn't get consistent results between the runtime and the TopologyTestDriver.

Matthias J Sax does provide an explanation of the difference here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59231281/2980494

Unfortunately it seems like there isn't  a good way to correct the behavior.  What I have done right now is add suppress() and then in the test I have to produce a dummy record to trigger the final results (due to the suppress)  The dummy record in the test is really not a great solution though.

Thanks for your time though.